# Wix: Unresolved reference to symbol 'Directory:INSTALLFOLDER' in section 'Fragment:'

Tags: wix

I’m trying to fix an installer for my Office add-in project, and am getting this error from AppOutputFromHeat. I’ve been mostly cutting/pasting from a project that has a working installer, and must have missed something somewhere.

```
    Unresolved reference to symbol 'Directory:INSTALLFOLDER' in section 'Fragment:'.    
    FROutlawSetup   C:\...\Setup\AppOutputFromHeat.wxs  13
```

At the top of AppOutputFromHeat I’ve got the following fragment:

```
<Fragment>
    <DirectoryRef Id="INSTALLFOLDER">
        <Directory Id="Data" Name="Data" />
    </DirectoryRef>
</Fragment>
```

And the relevent section in my product.wxs is

```
<Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
  <Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder">
    <Directory Id="FR" Name="FR">
      <Directory Id="INSTALLFOLDER" Name="$(var.PRODUCTNAME)" />
    </Directory>
  </Directory>
  <Directory Id="ProgramMenuFolder">
    <Directory Id="ApplicationProgramsFolder" Name="FR"/>
  </Directory>
</Directory>
```

Comment: is the variable PRODUCTNAME defined somewhere?

Comment: Yes, right under the Wix element

Comment: So... Have you found a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to have this kind of logic if you are dealing with windows. I added a directories.wxs file with this code. Note that "ProductNameFolder" is a local variable to my project and you can have a different name.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

```
  <?if $(var.Platform) = x64?>
    <!-- Program Files 64bit folder -->
    <Directory Id="ProgramFiles64Folder">
      <Directory Id="INSTALLFOLDER" Name="!(loc.ProductNameFolder)" />
    </Directory>
  <?else?>
    <!-- Program Files 32bit folder -->
    <Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder">
      <Directory Id="INSTALLFOLDER" Name="!(loc.ProductNameFolder)" />
    </Directory>
  <?endif?>


</Directory>
```